# HTML - Table columns not aligned properly

Tags: html, html-table, multiple-columns

I'm having some confusing issues with some content on my site, as I'm setting up some content in multiple columns, but on this specific page, the content isn't divided evenly, as one column appears to span about 60-65 % of the page without any justification (and even more frustratingly, I have similar pages which work with identical code).

```
<table border="2" frame="void" rules="none" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr width="100%">
            <td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; width: 40%;">
            <h3><font color="#0076be">Support<sup>1</sup></font></h3>

            <p>The Victorian Camps, Sports and Excursions Fund (CSEF) provides payments to assist eligible families (holders of valid means-tested concession cards or temporary foster parents) to cover the costs of school trips, camps and sporting activities..</p>

            <div style="padding: 8px; background-color: rgb(199, 215, 240);"><font color="#0076be">For more information, first contact your child&rsquo;s school.&nbsp;If further information is required, see </font><strong><a href="https://www.education.vic.gov.au/about/programs/Pages/csef.aspx" target="_blank">https://www.education.vic.gov.au/about/programs/Pages/csef.aspx</a></strong>.</div>

            <h3><font color="#0076be">Public transport concessions</font></h3>

            <p>In Victoria, all students aged 18 and under can travel on public transport at a concession rate using a Child myki, with only those aged 17 and 18 required to carry government-issued proof of age ID or proof of concession entitlement. All students are eligible to apply for a PTV School Student ID, which is necessary for purchasing a Victorian Student Pass.</p>

            <div style="padding: 8px; background-color: rgb(199, 215, 240);"><font color="#0076be">For more information, see </font><strong><u><a href="https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/ tickets/fares/concession/school-students" target="_blank">www.ptv.vic.gov.au/<br />
            tickets/fares/concession/school-students</a></u></strong><font color="#0076be">.</font></div>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 10px; vertical-align: top; width: 50%;">
            <p><img alt="" src="/getmedia/9f940c79-6c85-4650-8bde-82f35de44204/7_b.aspx" /></p>

            <h3><font color="#0076be">Transport</font></h3>

            <p>In country areas and some outer metropolitan areas, students who reside 4.8 km or more from their nearest Catholic school may be eligible for transport assistance. In locations where there is not enough demand to run a free school bus service, the Victorian Government provides a conveyance allowance to help with travel costs.</p>

            <div style="padding: 8px; background-color: rgb(199, 215, 240);"><font color="#0076be">For more information, first contact your child&rsquo;s school.&nbsp;If further information is required, see </font><strong><a href="https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/tickets/fares/concession/school-students" target="_blank">www.ptv.vic.gov.au/tickets/fares/concession/school-students</a></strong><br />
            <font color="#0076be">or:&nbsp;</font><strong><a href="https://www.ptv.vic.gov.au/getting-around/school-buses" target="_blank">www.ptv.vic.gov.au/getting-around/school-buses</a></strong>.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any pointers as to what might be causing this would really be appreciated!

Comment: perhaps some of the text is too long (i.e., the URL in the first cell, etc.) and the cell auto expands? It depends on the size of your container, for smaller narrower container it will be more prone to long strings or wide images. Also, it seems that the page is code two decades ago... is it for email? if not, perhaps turning that into a CSS (or bootstrap based) kind of template might make maintenance easier in the future. table and padding could be a pain to deal with with different browsers too.

Comment: It looks like you've specified the width of the first column as 40%, is that what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the width that you set in your `<td>`. One is 40% while the other one is 50%. You should put 50% on each. The width of all tds in one row should be equal to 100%. In your case, the second `<td>` adjusted its width itself to stretch at the edge of the table.